# How to get only the plots from gam.check

Tags: r, mgcv

When applying `gam.check` in the `mgcv` package, `R` produces some residual plots and basis dimension output. Is there a way to *only* produce the plots and not the printed output?

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(0)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=200)
b   <- gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3), data=dat)
plot(b, pages=1)
gam.check(b, pch=19, cex=.3)
```

Comment: All three plots that involve residuals? Or all plots and just skip the printed material? The plots are very easy to produce but if you just want one I don't want to show how to get all of them.

Comment: @GavinSimpson Sorry, I want all the plots (4) and not the printed material

Comment: I suspect this will end up being migrated to [so] as there isn't anything inherently statistical in your question, it's just about the right R incantations to use.

Comment: Yes I thought this too, after asking the question

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are four plots, from top left, moving down and across we have:

1. A QQ plot of the residuals
2. A histogram of the residuals
3. A plot of residuals vs the linear predictor
4. A plot of observed vs fitted values.

In the code below, I assume `b` contains your fitted model, as per your example. First some things we need

```
type <- "deviance"  ## "pearson" & "response" are other valid choices
resid <- residuals(b, type = type)
linpred <- napredict(b$na.action, b$linear.predictors)
observed.y <- napredict(b$na.action, b$y)
```

Note the last two lines are applying the `NA` handling method used when the model was fitted to the information on the `linear.predictors` and `y`, the stored copy of the response data.

The above code and that shown below is all given in the first 10 or so lines of the `gam.check()` source. To view this, just enter

```
gam.check
```

at the R prompt.

Each plot is produced as follows:

### QQ plot

This is produced via `qq.gam()`:

```
qq.gam(b, rep = 0, level = 0.9, type = type, rl.col = 2, 
       rep.col = "gray80")
```

### Histogram of residuals

This is produced using

```
hist(resid, xlab = "Residuals", main = "Histogram of residuals")
```

### Residuals vs linear predictor

This is produced using

```
plot(linpred, resid, main = "Resids vs. linear pred.", 
     xlab = "linear predictor", ylab = "residuals")
```

### Observed vs fitted values

This is produced using

```
plot(fitted(b), observed.y, xlab = "Fitted Values", 
     ylab = "Response", main = "Response vs. Fitted Values")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are now the two packages [gratia](https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/index.html) and [mgcViz](https://mfasiolo.github.io/mgcViz/index.html) which have functions to produce the `gam.check` output as ggplots which you can store as an object. The former doesn't print anything to console, the latter does.

```r
require(gratia)

appraise(b)
```

```r
require(mgcViz)

b = getViz(b)
check(b)
```